# Can't connect to MySQL on a Mac from a Mac on local network

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I've followed a number of guides and SO posts to log onto a MySQL instance on a local network M1 Mac Mini (8.0.27, Monterey 12.1) from an Intel MacBook Pro (8.0.27, Monterey 12.1).

I'm getting the following error from Workbench on the MacBook Pro:

[image]

From the following connection settings:

[image]

On the MySQL Mac Mini I've set up the user via the command line and Workbench both of which haven't worked. Here's a pic of Workbench:

[image]

IP address from System Preferences on the MySQL Mac Mini:

[image]

IP address from System Preferences on the MacBook Pro:

[image]

Things from other SO posts I've tried:

- Executing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`
- Restarting Mac Mini MySQL after making changes
- Checking I don't have Firewall running on either machine
- Double checking the user password
- Changing the Mac Mini `my.cnf` file to read `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`
- Successfully pinged the Mac Mini on 192.168.1.71

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: A the firewall has to let the traffic pass, mysql has to be configried to allow access from another computer last the user has to have grants to connect from a different computer, only when all three are correctly configured you can access the databse

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do. Can you see anything specific I've done wrong or missed off?

Comment: check if the firewall allows connections on  port 3306

Comment: before flushing privileges you should check the grants like i wrote in my first cpomment

Comment: Other things to double-check: is MySQL Server running on the Mac Mini? Can you connect to MySQL using a client on the Mac Mini specifying 127.0.0.1 as the host?

Comment: Ping uses UDP, whereas Mac protocol uses TCP/IP. It doesn't necessarily follow that you aren't being blocked if you only test ping. I would try using `telnet 192.168.1.71 3306` from the Macbook. That does not implement MySQL protocol, but it at least tests if you can open a socket to port 3306. If that succeeds, you rule out routing or firewall problems.

Comment: @nbk - no firewall is active and I've checked `SHOW GRANTS FOR "production.user"@"192.168.1.65"` and everything looks in order

Comment: @BillKarwin - all good running MySQL on the Mac Mini via localhost. `telnet` isn't on Macs anymore apparently so I used `nc -vz 192.168.1.71 3306` which got me `nc: connectx to 192.168.1.71 port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

Comment: In MySQL, "localhost" means to connect using a UNIX domain socket, not TCP/IP. You have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost to test that you can connect via TCP/IP, even if your client is on the same host. In the mysql client, run `status` and see the "Connection" line. Notice the difference if you connect to localhost versus 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to access MySQL via `Standard TCP/IP` but I was over `Standard TCP/IP over SSH`.

See below for the Workbench settings:

[image]